# trouble with precompilation. trying to deploy a rails app with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, pre-compilation

see this https://help.heroku.com/tickets/89264

basically, I updated my `config/environments/production.rb` file and followed
this advice https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally, but it still isn't working.

i just changed
`# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )`
to
`# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css )`

and then did the following:

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3- p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
~/collegeanswerz >>  git add public/assets
~/collegeanswerz >>  git commit -m "vendor compiled assets 2"
[master 23fa523] vendor compiled assets 2
 9 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 public/assets/home-73d942132cfdcc305dabf385494f8201.css
 create mode 100644 public/assets/home-73d942132cfdcc305dabf385494f8201.css.gz
 create mode 100644 public/assets/home.css
 create mode 100644 public/assets/home.css.gz
~/collegeanswerz >>  git push heroku master
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 2.30 KiB, done.
Total 12 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   Using rake (10.0.4)
   Using i18n (0.6.1)
   Using multi_json (1.7.3)
   Using activesupport (3.2.13)
   Using builder (3.0.4)
   Using activemodel (3.2.13)
   Using erubis (2.7.0)
   Using journey (1.0.4)
   Using rack (1.4.5)
   Using rack-cache (1.2)
   Using rack-test (0.6.2)
   Using hike (1.2.2)
   Using tilt (1.4.1)
   Using sprockets (2.2.2)
   Using actionpack (3.2.13)
   Using mime-types (1.23)
   Using polyglot (0.3.3)
   Using treetop (1.4.12)
   Using mail (2.5.3)
   Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
   Using arel (3.0.2)
   Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
   Using activerecord (3.2.13)
   Using activeresource (3.2.13)
   Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
   Using execjs (1.4.0)
   Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
   Using json (1.7.7)
   Using rdoc (3.12.2)
   Using thor (0.18.1)
   Using railties (3.2.13)
   Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
   Using dynamic_form (1.1.4)
   Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
   Using pg (0.12.2)
   Using bundler (1.3.2)
   Using rails (3.2.13)
   Using sass (3.2.9)
   Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
   Using uglifier (2.1.0)
   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
-----> WARNINGS:
   you have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
   To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:"
   ruby '1.9.3'"
   # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information."
-----> Rails plugin injection
   Injecting rails_log_stdout
   Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types      -> (none)
   Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 20.1MB
-----> Launching... done, v9
   http://fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:fast-reaches-9399.git
   28772c1..23fa523  master -> master
~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku open
Opening fast-reaches-9399... done
```

but I still got the same 500 error.

can anyone help me with this?  I am eager to deploy and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I read through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, but I still don't know what's wrong.  any help would be appreciated.  thanks.

EDIT:  I only added home.css to `config/environments/production.rb`.  I have other css files and javascript files though.  Do I need to add them along with home.css?  I'm confused as to what I need to add to this file and what I don't.

Heroku Logs:

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku logs
2013-06-21T18:09:38.400164+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-21T18:09:38.400164+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-21T18:09:38.400164+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-06-21T18:09:41.816038+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-21 18:09:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=37598
2013-06-21T18:09:41.806086+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-21 18:09:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-21T18:09:41.806250+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-21 18:09:41] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-05-15) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-21T18:09:41.846306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-21T18:09:42.983092+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 150.212.44.53 at 2013-06-21 18:09:42 +0000
2013-06-21T18:09:43.796440+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-06-21T18:09:43.918982+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (26.0ms)
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___725405358529282062_26831120'
2013-06-21T18:09:43.919413+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 121ms
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (home.css isn't precompiled):
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "home", :media => "all" %>
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% provide(:title, 'CollegeANSWERZ') %>
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:09:43.926737+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:09:43.930798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.44.53" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=997ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-21T18:10:43.120112+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2013-06-21T18:10:43.119811+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
2013-06-21T18:10:43.109481+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 130.49.162.173 at 2013-06-21 18:10:43 +0000
2013-06-21T18:10:43.115024+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-06-21T18:10:43.163822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="130.49.162.173" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=65ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___725405358529282062_26831120'
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% provide(:title, 'CollegeANSWERZ') %>
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (home.css isn't precompiled):
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "home", :media => "all" %>
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:10:43.159816+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
2013-06-21T18:10:43.284647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="130.49.162.173" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-21T18:31:38.978118+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 150.212.67.168 at 2013-06-21 18:31:38 +0000
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (home.css isn't precompiled):
2013-06-21T18:31:38.981955+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-06-21T18:31:38.983438+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
2013-06-21T18:31:38.984407+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "home", :media => "all" %>
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
2013-06-21T18:31:38.976788+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.67.168" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% provide(:title, 'CollegeANSWERZ') %>
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___725405358529282062_26831120'
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:31:38.988162+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T18:31:39.272322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.67.168" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-21T19:34:46.968884+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-06-21T19:34:51.384909+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-21T19:34:52.554631+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-21 19:34:52] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-06-21T19:34:52.554631+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:98:in `select'
2013-06-21T19:35:01.380745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-06-21T19:35:01.381015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-06-21T19:35:04.641711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-06-21T19:35:04.615493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-06-22T01:19:15.580026+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 23fa523 by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-22T01:19:15.610236+00:00 heroku[api]
: Release v9 created by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-22T01:19:15.645481+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 23fa523 by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-22T01:19:15.812011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-06-22T01:19:19.358919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 16312`
2013-06-22T01:19:24.227544+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-22T01:19:24.227544+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-22T01:19:26.887652+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-22T01:19:26.887652+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-22T01:19:26.887652+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:16312
2013-06-22T01:19:26.887652+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-22T01:19:26.887652+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-06-22T01:19:27.090788+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-22 01:19:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-22T01:19:27.091334+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-22 01:19:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=16312
2013-06-22T01:19:27.090788+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-22 01:19:27] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-05-15) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-22T01:19:27.339684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-22T01:19:30.066268+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 24.131.255.163 at 2013-06-22 01:19:30 +0000
2013-06-22T01:19:30.468648+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="24.131.255.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=488ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-22T01:19:30.525930+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (8.3ms)
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (layout.css isn't precompiled):
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-06-22T01:19:30.532648+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 64ms
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1612393333745609223_32479780'
2013-06-22T01:19:30.538131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2013-06-22T01:19:30.538131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "layout", :media => "all" %>
2013-06-22T01:19:30.537856+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2013-06-22T01:19:31.142918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="24.131.255.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=48ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-22T02:25:29.121546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-06-22T02:25:34.186899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-22T02:25:35.206762+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:98:in `select'
2013-06-22T02:25:35.206762+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-22 02:25:35] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-06-22T02:25:43.540073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-06-22T02:25:43.540320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-06-22T02:25:46.353635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-06-22T02:25:46.337936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

Comment: Can you post the heroku logs so we can see why you're getting an error?

Comment: Also we can't see your ticket link...

Comment: oh, I'm sorry about the ticket link.  basically, at first I didn't do any precompilation, and then I did what I said I did in my question and it's still not working.

Comment: what exactly are the heroku logs?  sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: In the console like you used to deploy your app type "heroku logs"

Comment: ok, got it.  i'll add it to the question because it's too long for a comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32195/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-larry-mckenzie)

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see your logs I did some looking around and you are not the only person to experience this. Try removing the locally compiled assets with: `git rm -r public/assets` then push to heroku. Leave the change you made to your production.rb.

Comment: odd have you tried using a different resource like application.css instead of home? It shouldn't matter but it's worth a try. I will keep looking around, I abandoned Heroku about a year ago for AWS Elastic Beanstalk so I am not super familiar with Heroku.

Comment: i think i fixed it.  I think you have it include all of your css and js files in production.rb other than application.css and application.js.  once I did that it worked.  see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post in StackOverflow and it's cool! I love seeing people help each other in the community.
Do you remember what caused your problem last time? It was:

ActionView::Template::Error (home.css isn't precompiled):
And you needed to add home.css to config/environments/production.rb. You need to tell production.rb that you need home.css. You need to tell that you need other css files than application.css.

Now, what error you see in your log after the deploy?

ActionView::Template::Error (layout.css isn't precompiled):
Figured out? Now you need to add layout.css as well. You can simply add like this:

%w( home.css layout.css )
Again, you need to add every css you need other than application.css to config/environments/production.rb. If you have some js files that you need to add other than application.js, you also need to add to config/environments/production.rb. I can see there are a lot of css files that you need to add there in your app(e.g. college_pages, essays, about_college, etc for css, about_college for js).
Reading your log is the first step for debugging, programming. Log always tells you something (if there is no logs, I wouldn't be able to point out your problem!). I'm sorry that I didn't tell you how to watch your logs (seems like you didn't know about it).

Here is the usage of reading your log:

Usage: heroku logs

display recent log output

-n, --num NUM        # the number of lines to display
 -p, --ps PS          # only display logs from the given process
 -s, --source SOURCE  # only display logs from the given source
 -t, --tail           # continually stream logs

Example:

$ heroku logs
 2012-01-01T12:00:00+00:00 heroku[api]: Config add EXAMPLE by email@example.com
 2012-01-01T12:00:01+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v1 created by email@example.com
You can do something like heroku logs -n 100 to see your last 100 lines of logs.

Hope this helps,
Keiko

---

Thanks so much for your help!  I know you're kinda going beyond your responsibility and I appreciate it.

I added all my other css and js files to production.rb and I deployed successfully!  The reason I was confused was that I didn't realize that I had to include all of them in production.rb.  I thought for some reason that application.css and application.js somehow made it so I didn't have to, and I thought that home.css was an exception for some reason.